# How to set a keyboard shortcut for converting from tabs to spaces in sublimetext2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

What is the option in the Key Bindings file that I would use to set up a keyboard shortcut for the menu item

```
View -> Indentation -> Convert Indentation To Spaces
```

I've tried the following, but can't figure out how to trigger the option I see in the above mentioned menu

```
{ "keys": ["super+t"], "command": "convert_to_tabs" },
{ "keys": ["shift+super+t"], "command": "convert_to_spaces" },
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

### Simple Version

Convert spaces to tabs (from Eric Muyser):

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+x"], "command": "unexpand_tabs", "args": { "set_translate_tabs": false } }
```

Convert tabs to spaces (from mVChr):

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+y"], "command": "expand_tabs", "args": { "set_translate_tabs": true } }
```

Original Answer Below

---

You could do it with [one command each](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/indentation.html) (`expand_tabs` and `unexpand_tabs`), but it would also be a good idea to toggle "Indent Using Spaces".  Here is a macro that I saw somewhere (I forget where.)

### Macro Version

**Tabs -> Spaces**

Save as "convert_tabs_to_spaces.sublime-macro" inside of your "Packages/User" folder

```
[
  {
    "args":
    {
      "set_translate_tabs": true
    },
    "command": "expand_tabs"
  }
]
```

Add this to your keybindings file:

```
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+x"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/convert_tabs_to_spaces.sublime-macro"} },
```

**Spaces -> Tabs**

Similar file name and keybinding

```
[
  {
    "args":
    {
      "set_translate_tabs": false
    },
    "command": "unexpand_tabs"
  }
]
```

I used this until I saw that you could left click the indentation setting in the Status Bar and change it from there.

### Edit:

### Plugin Version

[adapted from here](http://www.butlerpc.net/blog/2012/07/sublime-text-2-plugin-to-convert-tabs-to-spaces-on-save/)

**"convert_tabs_to_spaces.py"**

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class ConvertTabsToSpaces(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.run_command('expand_tabs', {"set_translate_tabs": True})
```

.

keybinding: `{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+x"], "command": "convert_tabs_to_spaces"},`

**"convert_spaces_to_tabs.py"**

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class ConvertSpacesToTabs(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.run_command('unexpand_tabs', {"set_translate_tabs": False})
```

.

keybinding: `{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+y"], "command": "convert_spaces_to_tabs"},`

Comment: The macro file seems unnecessary. It can just be: { 
  "keys": ["ctrl+shift+x"], "command": "unexpand_tabs", "args": {
      "set_translate_tabs": false
    }
}

Comment: @EricMuyser Awesome! Thanks! Also added the corollary to convert tabs to spaces: `{ "keys": ["whatever"], "command": "expand_tabs", "args": { "set_translate_tabs": true } }`

Comment: I was only able to get this working by setting `set_translate_tabs` to `true` in both options:

`{ "keys": ["super+ctrl+t"], "command": "unexpand_tabs", "args": { "set_translate_tabs": true } },
    { "keys": ["super+ctrl+s"], "command": "expand_tabs", "args": { "set_translate_tabs": true } }
`